# C++ split default parameter values between declaration and definition

Tags: c++

Is the following valid C++11? Both arguments to the constructor `NoWay::NoWay` have default values, but one is specified in the declaration and the other in the definition.

```
#include <iostream>

class NoWay {
private:
  int foo;
  bool bar;

public:
  explicit NoWay(int foo, bool bar = true);
  bool isGood();
};

NoWay::NoWay(int foo = 4, bool bar) {
  this->foo = foo;
  this->bar = bar;
}

bool NoWay::isGood() { return (foo == 4) && (bar == true); }

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  auto noway = NoWay();
  std::cout << noway.isGood() << std::endl;
}
```

This compiles without error under gcc

```
$ g++ --std=c++11 foo.cc
```

but clang rejects it

```
$ clang++ --std=c++11  foo.cc
foo.cc:13:18: error: addition of default argument on redeclaration makes this constructor a default constructor
NoWay::NoWay(int foo = 4, bool bar) {
                 ^     ~
foo.cc:9:12: note: previous declaration is here
  explicit NoWay(int foo, bool bar = true);
           ^
1 error generated.
Exit 1
```

Comment: Why not just hard code it then this->foo = 4?

Comment: You can't have an optional parameter before a required parameter, since you can only omit parameters at the end of the argument list.

Comment: @Barmar The intent is that both parameters be optional but the "syntactic manifestation of optionalness" be split between the declaration and the definition. Are you saying that the definition isn't even well-formed syntactically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That problem is known as core issue 1344: Adding new special member functions to a class via default arguments

According to [c++14 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf) that is in principal syntactically valid, the new default is simply added to the already defined.

> 8.3.6.6 Except for member functions of class templates, the default arguments in a member function definition that appears outside of the class definition are added to the set of default arguments provided by the member function declaration in the class definition;

But ill formed if

> 8.3.6.6 the program is ill-formed if a default constructor (12.1), copy or move constructor, or copy or move assignment operator (12.8) is so declared.

So clang is right. At least in C++14

Answer (score 1):

Clang is correct in reporting the error.  Quoting N4659, [dcl.fct.default], paragraph 6:

> Except for member functions of class templates, the default arguments in a member function definition that
>   appears outside of the class definition are added to the set of default arguments provided by the member
>   function declaration in the class definition; the program is ill-formed if a default constructor (15.1), copy
>   or move constructor, or copy or move assignment operator (15.8) is so declared.

It *is* valid to declare default values for other parameters when the (non-template) function is defined (or redeclared), as long as you don't specify a value for parameters that already have a default value and as long as the ODR is not violated across translation units.